# What does :: (double colon) mean before an identifier?

Tags: rust, syntax

[This line](https://github.com/rust-lang/libc/blob/4af234205f440be38d9036a5bdbcfeed55fb2ced/src/unix/linux_like/mod.rs#L2) is from Rust [libc](https://crates.io/crates/libc) crate. What is the use of double colon here? I thought its bringing `c_uint` in the scope from the crate root but I can't find where its defined in the crate root.

```
pub type speed_t = ::c_uint;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/paths.html#path-qualifiers

> Paths can be denoted with various leading qualifiers to change the meaning of how it is resolved.
>
> ```
> ::
> ```
>
> Paths starting with `::` are considered to be global paths where the segments of the path start being resolved from the crate root. Each identifier in the path must resolve to an item.

So your idea was correct, it is resolving from the crate root.

> I can't find where its defined in the crate root.

well `libc` doesn't in-and-of-itself define anything at the crate root, instead the crate root re-exports the content of the submodule matching the compilation target.

So [on unix](https://github.com/rust-lang/libc/blob/4af234205f440be38d9036a5bdbcfeed55fb2ced/src/lib.rs#L132-L137) the "crate root" contains anything exposed by the `fixed_width_ints` and `unix` submodules. The former is not really useful for you, but the latter... [does define a `c_uint` symbol](https://github.com/rust-lang/libc/blob/4af234205f440be38d9036a5bdbcfeed55fb2ced/src/unix/mod.rs#L11).

Comment: Thanks. I created a sample program to test this by re-exporting the content of submodule and then using :: to access a symbol in one of the submodule. I get an error `not found in the crate root` on compiling. But when i use `crate::`, it just compiles fine. Any idea what am i missing in my re-export? I was using mod submodule; and then pub use submodule::* in lib.rs to re-export.

Comment: @bornfree it works in `libc` because its compiled using 2015 Edition of Rust, the behavior changed in the 2018 Edition.

Answer (score 6):

This syntax works in `libc` because its compiled using the 2015 Edition of Rust. The [Paths](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/paths.html#path-qualifiers) reference includes a note:

> **Edition Differences:** In the 2015 Edition, the crate root contains a variety of different items, including external crates, default crates such as std and core, and items in the top level of the crate (including use imports).
>
> Beginning with the 2018 Edition, paths starting with :: can only reference crates.

In 2015, the `::c_uint` would find the re-exported type, whereas in 2018 it won't. There were a number of module resolution changes that are described with more detail in the [Edition Guide](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/edition-guide/rust-2018/module-system/path-clarity.html).

---

You can test it out on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=63840df84660cd6127fbf261cd78dc51) (you can change editions in the *advanced options* menu next to Debug and Stable).